# Regex to match word that is not in double or single quotes

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to write regex code that matches a word that is not in quotes. I used a look ahead and look behind to try and accomplish but it doesnt seem to be working. Here is my code

```
(?<!"")echo(?>!"")
```

I want it to match only when echo is not in single or double quotes i.e
match:

```
echo "i need help";
```

and not:

```
$str = " you can use echo to print out words";
```

by the way am using vb.net 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is to use capture groups and to match content inside quote before example:

```
("[^"]*"|'[^']*')|\becho\b
```

When the capture group 1 is empty, so you have matched "echo".

Note: the description of the content between quotes can be improved to handle escaped quotes.

Note2: if you project to parse PHP code, you need to handle Heredoc and Nowdoc syntaxes too since you can define a string with them.

So the full pattern becomes (ignoreWhiteSpaces option):

```
(?=['"<])
(
   # Heredoc/Nowdoc syntaxes:
    <<<(['"]?)(\w+)\2 \r?\n   # header
    (?>.*\r?\n)*?             # content
    \3;?\r?\n                 # close the string

  |

   # quoted strings with escaped quotes support

    "(?s)(?>[^\\"]+|\\.)*"
  |
    '(?s)(?>[^\\']+|\\.)*'
)

|
    \becho\b
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3D%5B%27%22%3C%5D)%0D%0A(%0D%0A%20%20%20%23%20Heredoc%2FNowdoc%20syntaxes%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%3C(%5B%27%22%5D%3F)(%5Cw%2B)%5C2%20%5Cr%3F%5Cn%20%20%20%23%20header%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(%3F%3E.*%5Cr%3F%5Cn)*%3F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20content%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5C3%3B%3F%5Cr%3F%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20close%20the%20string%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7C%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%23%20quoted%20strings%20with%20escaped%20quotes%20support%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22(%3Fs)(%3F%3E%5B%5E%5C%5C%22%5D%2B%7C%5C%5C.)*%22%0D%0A%20%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%27(%3Fs)(%3F%3E%5B%5E%5C%5C%27%5D%2B%7C%5C%5C.)*%27%0D%0A)%0D%0A%0D%0A%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cbecho%5Cb&i=echo%20%22abcd%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aecho%20%22abcd%20echo%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aecho%20%3C%3C%3CEOD%0D%0Aecho%0D%0AEOD%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%24a%20%3D%20array(%3C%3C%3C%27EOD%27%0D%0Aecho%20echo%0D%0AEOD%0D%0A%2C%20%27echo%27)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aecho%20%22%20%5C%22%20echo%20%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aecho%20%22%20%5C%5C%22%3B%20echo%20%22%5C%5C%5C%22%20echo%22%3B&o=x)

The advantage of this way is that it stay fast whatever the size of the string and it's deals with escaped quotes in strings.

You can see the number of steps needed to obtain a match with [regex101 debugger](https://regex101.com/r/uM2dI9/1).